# Cómo manipular el json obtenido de api graph en datagrid usando C#?

Tags: c#, json, jsonobject, jsonarray, deserialize

Esta pregunta es sobre cómo puedo trabajar con un json de tipo de datos que se obtienen de una consulta a la API GRAPH de Microsoft.
El resultado del json es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El objetivo es guardar toda la consulta json en una base de datos del servidor Sql.

He usado algunos métodos con newtonsoft pero no funciona para este tipo de json.

¿Alguien puede recomendarme qué puedo usar de C#?
¿Puedo mostrar este json en una cuadrícula de datos o guardar la información de la consulta en una base de datos rápidamente?
He usado diferentes métodos para usar inclusive método de convertir json a DataBase pero no logro agrupar los elementos de Json que requiero. Los ejemplos detallados en la red son muy planos pero nada con el json que obtengo de una api de microsoft.

Algunas respuestas de mensaje de error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ExtractChat.Form1+MessajesJson[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path '['@odata.context']', line 1, position 18.'

Gracias por todo.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Lo que pusiste abajo va dentro de la pregunta, que puedes [edit] todo lo que necesites. El campo de abajo se titula Tu Respuesta y es para intentar responderte. Por favor, borra esas no respuestas y edita tu pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Y bueh, todo debe ir en español; estás en SOes :)